# Password Protect any folder

Tags: batch-file

I used a tutorial at this [link](http://www.coolhackingtrick.com/2013/04/password-protect-any-folder-without-any.html) for protecting one of my important files,
The CODE is:

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
title coolhacking-tricks.blogspot.com
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto
UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST MyFolder goto MDMyFolder 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure to lock this folder? (Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren MyFolder "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to Unlock Your Secure Folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== coolhacks goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" MyFolder 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDMyFolder 
md MyFolder 
echo MyFolder created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```

But when I run lock.bat I don't get a screen asking for a password. Instead a screen appears and states: "the system cannot find the batch label specified" and suddenly the screen disappears without waiting a fraction of a second. The uploader was unable to help me with my problem.

Comment: Page gives a 404. Please show your code. And please don't shout. We're not deaf.

Comment: Right [link](http://www.coolhackingtrick.com/2013/04/password-protect-any-folder-without-any.html).

Comment: Can you post the your batch code? It looks like you tried to access a label (i.e. goto label), without :LABEL existing. Maybe it was a typo?

Comment: Except for the `UNLOCK` in line 5, which belongs at the end of line 4, the script works fine for me (tested on WinXP and Win7).

Comment: dude.. this don't actually "LOCK" the folder it only hides the folder :P if you turn on the option to see hidden files, the folder will appear

Answer (score 3):

Run this in the the root folder of your drive (assuming your script used the same GUID as the script on that page):

```
dir /b /s /a:s *.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
```

It'll take less time if you can narrow down the location to a particular parent folder.

Unhide the folder with these two commands:

```
attrib -s -h "C:\path\to\Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "C:\path\to\Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" newname
```

And next time steer clear of crappy "security tools" like that. It doesn't password-protect anything in the first place. It merely renames a folder an sets the `hidden` and `system` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use this (but re:

```
cls 
@ECHO OFF 
title Folder Private 
if EXIST "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren Private "HTG Locker" 
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to unlock folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== beef goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker" 
ren "HTG Locker" Private 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDLOCKER 
md Private 
echo Private created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```